# For Pokemon Go, the near by pokemon box doesn't update. Just stays the same. Everywhere

Tags: pokemon-go

The small grey box in the bottom right corner of the screen doesn't accurately show near by pokemon. There could be an eevee in my front yard, and after walking a mile, it still shows the eevee in the box. No new pokemon show up either. I've tried deleting and redownloading the app, checking settings, and restarting my phone. I tried talking with support from the company and they won't respond. Is anyone else having this issue? Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found so far is to close the application completely and relaunch it. This problem extends to Pokéstops not refreshing until you've moved far away enough and restarted your application.

Reinstalling the game will not solve the problem, personally I've reinstalled the game over 10 times and had it run from both my SD card and Device Storage.

*Running on Samsung S4 Android Lollipop 5.0.1*

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced some errors with this as well - it's probably related to the server issues they've had this week. Thus there isn't really a fix.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, it seems that old entries remain in the nearby box. It makes it incredibly difficult to use the footprints to find nearby Pokemon.

The solution to this would be to restart the app. After logging in the nearby box should be refreshed and work correctly for a little bit. When hunting a rare Pokemon, I refresh the app constantly just to make sure it's correctly updated.

The other thing that could happen is that you can't log in for a period of time or get the "servers are busy" error. Then you will just have to try again later.